# AuthLogic automatically loads errors into @base and populates those errors on a signin form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authlogic

```
(rdb:1) @account_session = AccountSession.new  
# => <AccountSession: no credentials provided>
(rdb:1) @account_session.errors
# => <Authlogic::Session::Validation::Errors:0x213cc78 @errors={}, @base=#<AccountSession: no credentials provided>>
```

How do I prevent this?  Also note, that credentials can't be provided in advance because that will populate the :new form with (incorrect) data.  A new signin form should be blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reproduced this on a vanilla Rails install that contains only AuthLogic.  It revealed that the behavior described in this question is actually AuthLogic design behavior.  I don't like this because calling #new on the model shouldn't result in errors if none really exist.  And it's also funky if a form has UI elements that show error styling for @base errors.  I'll address this on the gem's github issues.

Comment: My message to AuthLogic owner:

... Why add @base errors on a new Session instance? ... I'm thinking of forking Authlogic to remove this behavior. ...  Gavin

His response:

I agree, I'll see what I can do to change this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you validating your model in one of your methods/before-filters,etc?